# Define new column data during PHP export

Tags: php

I was told that "\t" would 'tell' Excel that it is a new column data.

However, it is just an empty space and all my single line data are in ONE cell instead of seperate columns.

Did i do anything wrong?

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$contents.=$row['idUsers']."\t";
$contents.=$row['First_Name']."\t";
$contents.=$row['Last_Name']."\t";
$contents.=$row['Email_Address']."\t";
$contents.=$row['Verified']."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating a CSV file for MS Excel, you'll find that Excel's separator is locale specific, so what might work for one person won't necessarily work for another.

One way to try and force the issue is to use a `sep=<x>` line as the very first line of your CSV file; so if you initially define $content using

```
$contents = "sep=\t\n";
```

before starting your `while` loop, you may find that this allows MS Excel to correctly identify what separator you're using when the file you generate is loaded into Excel

And rather than "roll your own" csv format file, why don't you make use of PHP's built-in [fputcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function, which will also handle quoting strings and generally simplify things for you

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the CSV format?

Replace your '\t' by a comma..

```
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$contents.=$row['idUsers'].",";
$contents.=$row['First_Name'].",";
$contents.=$row['Last_Name'].",";
$contents.=$row['Email_Address'].",";
$contents.=$row['Verified']."\n";
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values